# How to construct manual custom fields out of a foreach array loop?

Tags: php, wordpress, plugins, hook

I have two custom fields which I hooked into the Ultimate Member - User Profile & Membership Plugin for Wordpress..

```
"username" => "Username",
"license_keys" => "License Key",
```

The foreach loop creates the fields perfectly, but I want to have the value of the license key field auto generated by `$rand_str = generateRandomString();`.

The first obvious thing is it's in a foreach loop, so both value fields on the outputted HTML become random strings and also change every time the page refreshes it changes to a new value.

I also tried `if ($value = "License Key")` statement to output a different `$html` if returned true, but since I'm in the foreach loop it applied the different `$html` to both fields anyhow.

So how can I control both fields outside the loop and apply individual logic to each?

```
/* make our new tab hookable */

add_action('um_account_tab__license', 'um_account_tab__license');

function um_account_tab__license($info) {
    global $ultimatemember;
    extract($info);

    $output = $ultimatemember->account->get_tab_output('license');
    if ($output) {
        echo $output;
    }
}

/* Finally we add some content in the tab */

add_filter('um_account_content_hook_license', 'um_account_content_hook_license');

function um_account_content_hook_license($output) {
    ob_start();

    function generateRandomString($length = 15) {
        $characters = '0123456789abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ';
        $charactersLength = strlen($characters);
        $randomString = '';

        for ($i = 0; $i < $length; $i++) {
            $randomString .= $characters[rand(0, $charactersLength - 1)];
        }

        return $randomString;
    }

    $custom_fields = [
        "username" => "Username",
        "license_keys" => "License Key",
    ];
    $rand_str = generateRandomString();

    foreach ($custom_fields as $key => $value) {
        $fields[$key] = array(
            'title' => $value,
            'metakey' => $key,
            'type' => 'select',
            'label' => $value,
        );

        global $ultimatemember;
        $id = um_user('ID');
        $field_value = get_user_meta(um_user('ID'), $key, true) ? : '';

        $html = '<div class="um-field um-field-'.$key.'" data-key="'.$key.'">
                    <div class="um-field-label">
                        <label for="'.$key.'">'.$value.'</label>
                    <div class="um-clear"></div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="um-field-area">
                        <input class="um-form-field valid "
                        type="text" name="'.$key.'"
                        id="'.$key.'" value="'.$field_value.'"
                        placeholder=""
                        data-validate="" data-key="'.$key.'">
                    </div>
                </div>';

        echo $html;
    }

    $fields = apply_filters( 'um_account_secure_fields', $fields, $id );
    $output .= ob_get_contents();
    ob_end_clean();

    return $output;
}
```

UPDATED CODE: The problem with this is that it returns only the last item in the `$field_value` array

```
foreach ($custom_fields as $key => $value) {
    $fields[$key] = array(
        'title' => $value,
        'metakey' => $key,
        'type' => 'select',
        'label' => $value,
    );

//$field_value = get_user_meta(um_user('ID'), $key, true) ? : '';
$field_value = [
    'username' => [
        'fieldvalue' => get_user_meta($id, $key, true) ? : '',
        //etc
    ],
    'license_key' => [
        'fieldvalue' => generateRandomString(),
        // etc
    ],
];


foreach ($field_value as $i => $field){
//echo um_profile_id();
$fieldsvalue[$i] = array(
    'field_value' => $field,
);

$html = '<div class="um-field um-field-'.$value['label'].'" data- 
key="'.$value['label'].'">
            <div class="um-field-label">
                <label for="'.$value['label'].'">'.$value['name'].'</label>
            <div class="um-clear"></div>
            </div>
            <div class="um-field-area">
                <input class="um-form-field valid "
                type="text" name="'.$value['label'].'"
                id="'.$value['label'].'" value="'.$field['fieldvalue'].'"
                placeholder=""
                data-validate="" data-key="'.$value['label'].'">
            </div>
        </div>';

}
echo $html;
}
```

Comment: Can you simplify your question? There's a lot of theory and desires in there. If you want to have the value of the license key field auto generated by `$rand_str = generateRandomString()` then what happens when you try, such as `$foo['license_field'] =  generateRandomString();`?

Comment: Understood I will try now, I just want to auto generate the L_K field somehow and it seem everything I try applies to both fields

Comment: What is the `L_K` field you refer to. And "what" do you try that applies to both fields and what do you mean by "both fields"? Fields in the DB, array, which array? There's a lot of code and a lot of references in there to "license keys" and "L K"

Comment: Sorry L_K as in "license key", and the custom input fields the html outputs Screenshot -> https://imgur.com/a/7j1Vy

Comment: looking at it now it seems i need to modify the output of $field_value = get_user_meta(um_user('ID'), $key, true) ? : ''; which populates the value="'.$field_value.'" for the html input tag

Comment: Well sure, we can't tell you where in your code you should be setting values. lol. Where in your code do you want the random value adding to the array key?  Perhaps remove any obsolete code from above as there's a lot of vars and indexes, a lot, no offence but it's a bit unorganised and makes it hard to read... Did you try`$foo['license_field'] = generateRandomString();`?

Comment: yes i get Warning: Illegal string offset 'license_key'

Comment: Theres two fields I want to auto generate the value of the License Key Field with a random string.

Comment: Do you mean like this `$custom_fields = ["username" => "Username", "license_keys" => generateRandomString(),];`?

Comment: Yes that outputs a random string to the textbox label, the variable that controls the input textbox value is $field_value = get_user_meta(um_user('ID'), $key, true) ? : ''; I need to figure out how to change the $field_value variable per item in the array i guess.

Comment: You say "*I need to figure out how to change the $field_value variable per item in the array i guess*" Change the `$field_value` to what? Per what item - it just loops `$custom_fields` array which is just a mock array with `username` and `license_key`. We have no clue about your code, what it does, how it works and how it is supposed to work. A lot of it makes no sense as it seems to be mock while you code and test. I really don't know what you want, but it seems like it should be very simple, just explain what part of the code you want the random value to be in

Comment: `$field_value` outputs to the $html code which creates the divs for the input boxes `value="'.$field_value.'"` <-- That's the field which i need the random string to appear in when the html echos out.. But I dont want it to put random strings in both text boxes just the license_key one

Comment: I think you need a large refactor. As you code stands it's hard to manipulate the data you have and use it in the way you want to. You use an array to loop which has 2 values, and each value has very specific requirements within the loop. This means you will need lots of `if current loop is this thing, do this, else do this` and that sets you up for a world of pain if you ever add another thing in the array.

Comment: ok question then how can i drop the foreach loop and just output two divs. how can i call the array items individually?

Comment: I just dumped the array i will post my solution i think i figured it out

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So they way your code is now you'd need to fill it with IFs and ELSEs to cater for each value in the `$custom_fields` array which is looped. As you need to set numerous variables based on which thing you have, such as `if is username then do this` else `if is license_key do this`.

This is a bad design and the answer to your question using that code would be a lot of changes.

So instead I suggest a slight refactor.

Adding another dimension to the `$custom_fields` array, so each initial key are your main items (license_key, username etc) then each value for those keys is a sub array containing all the values you need for each item.

For example:

```
$custom_fields = [
    'username' => [
        'name' => 'Username',
        'field_value' => set_user_meta(um_user('ID'), $key, true) ?: '',
        'label' => 'Username',
        'title' => 'Username',
        //etc
    ],
    'license_key' => [
        'name' => 'License Key',
        'field_value' => generateRandomString(),
        'label' => 'License Key',
        'title' => 'License Key',
        // etc
    ],
];

foreach ($custom_fields as $key => $values) {
    // The code
}
```

Then in your loop to satisfy the values you need, such as in the HTML, you'd access the same sub array key names for each one, such as `$values['field_value']` and `$values['label']` etc.
So on each loop it doesn't matter what the current item is in the loop (license_key, username etc), because you already set the data for each item before the loop, so the things in the loop are generic and named the same for all items (and obviously have different values).

You can remove items and add items to and from the array, and the loop will just use them as required.

Comment: it returns `get_user_meta(um_user('ID'), $key, true) ? : '';` for both fields. And `$field_value = $key = 'license_keys'` inserts random keys into both boxes.

Comment: All seems to work except `'field_value' => get_user_meta($id, $key, true) ? : '',` doesnt like it. Outputs `Array` to the text box the second text box which is license key has the random string in it :D very close

Comment: I see why `get_user_meta(um_user('ID'), $key, true) ? : '';` gets made within the foreach loop it doesnt exists outside of it.

Comment: I updated the code in the post the problem with it is that it returns only the last item in the `$field_value` array :( Screenshot -> https://imgur.com/a/DgSCB

Comment: What is `$key` inside the foreach loop? And thus what is it outside the loop? It's just the username, which is set before the loop

Comment: $key returns the name of the key in the custom_fields array so username and license_key

Comment: Yes, so outside the array anything that would have previously been `$key` with the old array is now just the parent key. As such it'll also still be the `$key` in the new array being looped. So can set it outside the loop or in, depending on the requirements

Comment: I refactored based on your suggestions and worked it all out thank you very much!

Comment: No problem - glad to help :)